# How to use non UTF-8 characters in Arrow package with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, encoding, apache-arrow

I have created a parquet object from a 21GB sized file. I would like to use dplyr on it, to wrangle, summarize etc. the data.
This is my code, transforming the csv to parquet, until I get the error:

```
library(arrow)

dir.create("tickets_22_parts")

tickets_arrow <- open_dataset("tickets_2022.csv", format = "csv")
write_dataset(tickets_arrow, "tickets_22_parts", format ="parquet")
    
arrow_files <- list.files("tickets_22_parts", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
    
arrow_df <- open_dataset("tickets_22_parts",
                          schema = schema(date=date32(),
                                          channel= string(),
                                          station= string())


table <- arrow_df %>% 
  group_by(station) %>% 
  summarize(passengers=sum(trips)) %>% 
  collect()
```

> ```
> Error in `compute.arrow_dplyr_query()`: ! Invalid: Invalid UTF8 payload.
> ```

I know that I have columns which contain letters like: é,ő,ú, so might not be UTF-8 encoded. How to resolve this without touching the original csv file that I had transformed to parquet in the first place? Or only that way I can solve it? Thank you

Comment: How did you get from CSV to Parquet in the first place? That's likely where things need to change, not here at the querying stage.

Comment: Whatever package/implementation that was able to save the parquet can probably open it again so you don't necessarily have to go back to the csv but there's probably nothing you can do from R at this point.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible example? If you can include either _a few rows_ of the file contents (or at least representative characters) allowing us to test it on characters that you are seeing. Also, while I don't know that it's a factor, often I find some OSes deal with non-ASCII very differently than others (I'm looking at you, Windows), and the locale is also influential here; please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: I am going to try and upload a reproducible example, with all session info etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing this as a reproducible question: we cannot run it ourselves. When I suggested a few rows of the file contents, I meant that you could include the raw file contents (for a few lines, containing at least some of the problematic text) in a [code block] (since you're converting from CSV to parquet).